# PHP-FPM process is growing and getting more and more memory

Tags: php, memory, memory-leaks

I have some process of php-fpm always growing.

Showing the memory used (with ps command) shows this.

I have tried two things:

1) strace, but there's tons and tons of information. It's a Symfony framework and I see tons of files being accessed or opened, but no clue at all. Neverending log ... each 1 or 2 or 3 seconds, it shows 2000 lines of trace suddenly.

I see this:

```
fstat(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1029, ...}) = 0
fstat(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1029, ...}) = 0
fstat(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1029, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1029, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 7, 0) = 0x7f88da53d000
munmap(0x7f88da53d000, 1029)            = 0
close(7)                                = 0
chdir("/")                              = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {21720, 148391054}) = 0
times({tms_utime=6933, tms_stime=7614, tms_cutime=0, tms_cstime=0}) = 1720128933
close(11)                               = 0
setitimer(ITIMER_PROF, {it_interval={0, 0}, it_value={0, 0}}, NULL) = 0
umask(022)                              = 0
sendto(12, "\1\0\0\0\1", 5, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 5
close(12)                               = 0
fcntl(6, F_SETLK, {l_type=F_UNLCK, l_whence=SEEK_SET, l_start=0, l_len=0}) = 0
munmap(0x7f88ba000000, 2097152)         = 0
setitimer(ITIMER_PROF, {it_interval={0, 0}, it_value={0, 0}}, NULL) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {21720, 149294252}) = 0
accept(0,
```

then it stops for 1-5 seconds, and the it shows 2000 lines of a lot of lstat files of the framework... houndreds of blocks like this one (this is ONE as example, but all blocks are **different**

```
lstat("/var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/vendor/composer/../symfony/swiftmailer-bundle/DependencyInjection/SmtpTransportConfigurator.php", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1029, ...}) = 0
lstat("/var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/vendor/composer/../symfony/swiftmailer-bundle/DependencyInjection", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/vendor/composer/../symfony/swiftmailer-bundle", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/vendor/composer/../symfony", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/vendor/composer", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/vendor", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0710, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/var/www/vhosts", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/var/www", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/var", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
```

2) lsof but I can't get information of what script is, or why.

```
COMMAND   PID        USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  cwd    DIR              202,1     4096       2 /
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  rtd    DIR              202,1     4096       2 /
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  txt    REG              202,1  4821232 1537261 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/sbin/php-fpm
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  DEL    REG                0,5          1406882 /dev/zero
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  DEL    REG                0,5          1406876 /dev/zero
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    27000    1985 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.23.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    26258   24695 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  DEL    REG                0,5          1406861 /dev/zero
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    47600    1991 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    47648    1995 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.23.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    93128    1968 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.23.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    35688    1983 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.23.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   134624 1328699 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/zip.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   247952   50760 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1.1.28
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    83816   50761 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexslt.so.0.8.17
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    31752 1328672 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/xsl.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    47816 1328671 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/xmlwriter.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    81096 1328675 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/xmlrpc.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    31528 1328674 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/xmlreader.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   383544   53078 /usr/lib/libtidy-0.99.so.0.0.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    52360 1328682 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/tidy.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    14792 1328666 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/sysvshm.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    10600 1328667 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/sysvsem.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    14888 1328669 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/sysvmsg.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   998080 1328679 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/sqlite3.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   303432 1328693 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/soap.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   695312   51937 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaspell.so.15.2.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    23080 1328670 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/pspell.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    35816 1328668 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/posix.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   270512 1328697 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/phar.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   139048 1328680 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/pgsql.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    27896 1328677 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/pdo_sqlite.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   194544    9381 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5.8
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    44600 1328681 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/pdo_pgsql.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    27768 1328687 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/pdo_odbc.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    31672 1328684 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/pdo_mysql.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   110168 1328678 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/pdo.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   427552   51744 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so.2.0.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    68680 1328686 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/odbc.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   134296 1328683 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/mysqli.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1  1674464 1328665 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/mbstring.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    72872 1328691 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/ldap.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    43624 1328700 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/json.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    55304   25752 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuio.so.55.1
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1  2496856   25754 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.55.1
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   482160 1328692 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/intl.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   117288    2603 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1.0.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    55904   21215 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0.83.1
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1  1100216   50574 /usr/lib/libc-client.so.2007e.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    89480 1328695 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/imap.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   166032    1979 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    39272   50718 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7.3.1
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    73640   25834 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   273832   51273 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.9.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1  2087104   51314 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3.so.3.4.4
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    96504   51337 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblqr-1.so.0.3.2
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   353392   51331 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblcms2.so.2.0.6
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   138448   51307 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1  2707304    9717 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.2.0.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1  1200744    6527 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.2.0.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   426816 1328701 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/imagick.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    22640   25828 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    14456   25826 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   137728   25830 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1  1285552   25832 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   694800   25840 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6.12.1
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   363264   51325 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8.0.2
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   149904    2138 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0.54.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    72520   51670 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXpm.so.4.11.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   389088 1328694 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/gd.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1  5045800 1328698 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/fileinfo.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1  1115136    2154 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.2
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    14656   25804 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.4800.2
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    46944   52829 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libenchant.so.1.6.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    23904 1328688 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/enchant.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   172216 1328673 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/dom.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1  1756696   24914 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdb-5.3.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    52776 1328690 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/dba.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    39224    1997 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.23.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   870240   25802 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   304072   25885 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5.0.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    60928   25881 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1.0.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   166128   25883 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0.0.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    31104   25780 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    89904   25873 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18.1.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   204168   25878 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4.1.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   661872   25875 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8.0.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   560808   25887 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26.0.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    35920   25889 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0.1.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    14256    2172 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1.5
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    76192   25740 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6.5.1
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   408472   25738 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.1.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   264256   25891 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3.0.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   109296   25916 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2.0.25
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    43664   25861 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0.1
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    14648    1960 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2.1
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   186872   25865 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3.1
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   860392   25867 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3.3
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   219336   25734 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6.2
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   207640   25732 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4.2
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1  1239440   25744 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30.6.2
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   322928   10117 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2.10.5
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    59640   10118 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2.10.5
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   301376   25869 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   113584   25923 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   207208   25736 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11.6.15
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   452992   10557 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.4.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    89256 1287184 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/curl.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    35344 1328676 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/bcmath.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   256760 1328685 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/mysqlnd.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1 15185280 2826090 /opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/lib64/liboneagentphp.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1  4816792 2826084 /opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/lib64/liboneagentloader.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   438752 1328689 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/opcache.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1  1385896 1283865 /opt/plesk/php/7.2/lib/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_7.2.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  DEL    REG                0,5          1406862 /dev/zero
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1  1668976   28956 /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    89696    1965 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1  1566440   51083 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1 25913104   25753 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55.1
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    80496    2002 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.17.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   456632    2066 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1  1636360   25757 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55.1
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   919168    1001 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20.0.5
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   137400    2004 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   130224    2073 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    18624    2107 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1.1.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   138696    1970 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1  1868984    1971 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1  2361856   21565 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   428384   21561 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1  1809656   25949 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.3
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    31232    1987 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1.1.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    14608    1973 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1  1088952    1967 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    31712    1996 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   104864    2120 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1    66800    2111 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0.4
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   522664   25784 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.3.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   101200    1975 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   548432     747 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liboneagentproc.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   162632    1969 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  DEL    REG                0,5          1406870 /dev/zero
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  DEL    REG                0,5          1406867 /dev/zero
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  DEL    REG                0,5          1406866 /dev/zero
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  DEL    REG                0,5          1406865 /dev/zero
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  DEL    REG                0,5          1406864 /dev/zero
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  DEL    REG                0,5          1406863 /dev/zero
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  DEL    REG                0,5          1406846 /dev/zero
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  DEL    REG                0,5          1406845 /dev/zero
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  DEL    REG                0,5          1406844 /dev/zero
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  DEL    REG                0,5          1406843 /dev/zero
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  DEL    REG                0,5          1406842 /dev/zero
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  DEL    REG                0,5          1406841 /dev/zero
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  DEL    REG                0,5          1406840 /dev/zero
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  DEL    REG                0,5          1406839 /dev/zero
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk  mem    REG              202,1   536520    2093 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0.14.0
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk    0u  unix 0xffff8803a285a000      0t0 1406893 /var/www/vhosts/system/mywebsite.com/php-fpm.sock type=STREAM
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk    1w  FIFO               0,10      0t0 1407453 pipe
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk    2w  FIFO               0,10      0t0 1407454 pipe
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk    3r   CHR                1,9      0t0      11 /dev/urandom
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk    4w   CHR                1,8      0t0      10 /dev/random
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk    6u   REG              202,1        0  513276 /tmp/.ZendSem.1t93Xa (deleted)
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk    8r   CHR                1,9      0t0      11 /dev/urandom
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk    9w  FIFO               0,10      0t0 1406869 pipe
php-fpm 25690 www_plesk   11u  unix 0xffff8803a2bf8800      0t0 1418861 type=STREAM
```

Any other chance to get real information of the script running ?

More info:

part of the top

```
top - 21:13:22 up  6:11,  2 users,  load average: 0.84, 0.92, 0.89
Tasks: 206 total,   1 running, 205 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 15.5 us,  5.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 78.8 id,  0.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.2 st
KiB Mem : 16431376 total,  8608756 free,  2660328 used,  5162292 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  1048572 total,  1048572 free,        0 used. 13156496 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                        
 9573 www_p+  20   0  631700  99808  54084 S  30.9  0.6   0:01.86 php-fpm                                                                                                                        
 9645 www_p+  20   0  603164  50004  27864 S  11.6  0.3   0:00.35 php                                                                                                                            
26995 www_p+  20   0  773664 231460  43620 S   6.6  1.4   2:06.97 php-fpm                                                                                                                        
25685 www_p+  20   0  778512 238372  43632 S   3.7  1.5   2:57.93 php-fpm                                                                                                                        
25688 www_p+  20   0  793032 251636  42408 S   3.7  1.5   2:16.99 php-fpm                                                                                                                        
25940 www_p+  20   0  789220 250440  45004 S   3.7  1.5   2:14.46 php-fpm                                                                                                                        
25690 www_p+  20   0  861668 251364  47144 S   2.3  1.5   2:27.00 php-fpm                                                                                                                        
25831 www_p+  20   0  862860 251556  46112 S   2.3  1.5   2:20.00 php-fpm
```

output of a strace of one of them (php-fpm) with -c attribute (10 seconds):

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 63.17    0.018411           0    409063       700 lstat
 27.45    0.008000         727        11           accept
  2.45    0.000713           0     20071           fstat
  2.00    0.000584           0      6582           mmap
  1.45    0.000424           0      6905           close
  1.21    0.000353           0      6872           open
  1.04    0.000304           0      6588           munmap
  0.38    0.000110           0      3065           clock_gettime
  0.15    0.000043           0       247           lseek
  0.15    0.000043           1        33           sendto
  0.14    0.000041           0       912           read
  0.09    0.000027           0      1214           gettimeofday
  0.09    0.000026           3         9           brk
  0.08    0.000022           0       383        31 stat
  0.08    0.000022           0       706       288 access
  0.07    0.000020           0        55           fcntl
  0.00    0.000000           0        32           write
  0.00    0.000000           0       384           poll
  0.00    0.000000           0        88           rt_sigaction
  0.00    0.000000           0        11           rt_sigprocmask
  0.00    0.000000           0        22           ioctl
  0.00    0.000000           0         6           madvise
  0.00    0.000000           0        44           setitimer
  0.00    0.000000           0        21           socket
  0.00    0.000000           0        21        11 connect
  0.00    0.000000           0       375           recvfrom
  0.00    0.000000           0        11           shutdown
  0.00    0.000000           0        22           setsockopt
  0.00    0.000000           0        11           getsockopt
  0.00    0.000000           0        11           getcwd
  0.00    0.000000           0        22           chdir
  0.00    0.000000           0       350       350 readlink
  0.00    0.000000           0        33           umask
  0.00    0.000000           0        22           times
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           restart_syscall
  0.00    0.000000           0        10           sendmmsg
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.029143                464213      1380 total
```

Notes:

- no crontabs involved
- if I kill one of those ram-consumer growing process, they start again (from about 30Mb, and grows again slowly ...) about 100Mb of growth each 15 minutes ....

Comment: can you `ssh` into the server and issue a `top` command?

Comment: @zak there you go (more info edited)

Comment: what happens when you kill the top two processes using so much CPU?  IE `kill -9 9573` and `kill -9 9645` -- Do they restart?

Comment: They are consuming right now about 400Mb each one (the started with 30Mb about 1 hour ago) ... if I kill them YES, they start again (from 30Mb and growing ...)

Comment: Given that you clearly can see the PID of the growing process, you can do the following to find out more about at least how that process was started.  "cat /proc/<pid>/cmdline"

Comment: Yes, I tried @TimBoddy, but no information at all ...  just php-fpm: pool mywebsite.com  The problem is that the pool created (5) are always eating memory !

Answer (score 1):

Your primary problem of memory usage is something that you're going to have to attach a debugger or profiler to diagnose and is most likely a memory leak inside the application itself rather than anything inherent to PHP. As a stopgap measure you could configure FPM to recycle its workers more frequently to release the accumulated memory.

http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php#pm.max-requests

The secondary problem that you have is your composer autoloader is still traversing the filesystem on every load, which seems to be why you have such a huge number of `lstat` calls. This has no effect on your memory usage, but it's a lot of needless IO that can be avoided very simply:

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/autoloader-optimization.md#optimization-level-1-class-map-generation